# Copy audio files to sd card, parse on file level or trigger refresh of Mediastore

Tags: android, mediastore

I am coding a music player in Android Java. I am using AVD and copied audio files manually to the internal and sd card storage via `adb push`. I noticed that the Mediastore does not get updated when copying on file level.

1. Is it a good practice to use Mediastore or do you advice that I operate completely on file level?
2. If Mediastore is the way to get information about audio files, do I manually add files to Mediastore which are not found? Or do I have to trigger a complete update of the Mediastore?

Comment: The only and quickesg way to populate mediastore is through a reboot. I have found no other way

Comment: Would it make sense to rely on the MediaStore and start an async background task and programmatically go through the files and update the MediaStore manually?

Comment: There is no point updating Mediastore programmatically as it gets maintained by Android processes. Any changes you make will be overwritten